# how to configure 2 endpoints via traefik PathPrefix

Tags: traefik

I try to used traefik 2 with 2 endpoints

toto.xxx/tata

toto.xxx/titi

But any endpoints work.

My docker-compose is

```
version: "3.7"
services:
traefik:
image: traefik:v2.2
restart: unless-stopped
environment:
  - DUCKDNS_TOKEN=${DUCKDNS_TOKEN}
ports:
  - 80:80
  - 444:443
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  - ${TRAEFIK_ACME}/acme.json:/etc/traefik/acme.json
  - ${TRAEFIK_CONFIG}/traefik.yaml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yaml:ro
  - ${TRAEFIK_LOG}:/etc/traefik/traefik_log
labels:
  # General
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  # Traefik internal rules
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
  # hostname
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`ubuntu.local`) && PathPrefix(`/traefik`)"
  # Authentication
  # - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=USER:PASSWORD"
  # - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-auth"
  # HTTPS
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
  # Internal port
  - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
  # Prefixes
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.prefix-traefik.stripprefix.prefixes=/traefik"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik.stripprefix.forceslash=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=prefix-traefik@docker"
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see from the snippet you share how did you try to configure traeifk with these endpoints. can you add more info?

In case you are trying to proxy traffic to other services behind the proxy, you need to set labels on these services with the needed router rules. Below is an example of doing this

```
 proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.2
    command:
      - '--log.level=DEBUG'
      - '--providers.docker=true'
      - '--entryPoints.web.address=:80'
      - '--providers.providersThrottleDuration=2s'
      - '--providers.docker.watch=true'
      - '--providers.docker.swarmMode=true'
      - '--providers.docker.swarmModeRefreshSeconds=15s'
      - '--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false'
      - '--providers.docker.defaultRule=Host("lvh.me")'
      - '--accessLog.bufferingSize=0'
      - '--api=true'
      - '--api.dashboard=true'
      - '--api.insecure=true'
      - '--ping.entryPoint=web'
      - '--providers.redis.endpoints=redis:6379'
      - '--providers.redis.rootkey=traefik'
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '8080:8080'
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik
    networks:
      - traefik

  mailcatcher:
    image: sj26/mailcatcher
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.tags=public
        - traefik.http.services.mailcatcher.loadbalancer.server.port=1080
        - traefik.http.routers.mailcatcher.rule=Host(`lvh.me`) &&  PathPrefix(`/mailcatcher`)
        - traefik.http.routers.mailcatcher.service=mailcatcher
        - traefik.http.routers.mailcatcher.entrypoints=web
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        'max-size': '10m'
        'max-file': '5'
    networks:
      - traefik
```